# parsing sensitive data puts asterisks in wrong places

Tags: php, regex

A string parameter is passed to the function – below are various samples of possible input data
  The function receives this data as a string, not an array, json or other data formats
  The function should parse the string and mask sensitive data.
  Sensitive data should be masked (replaced) with an Asterix (*) character.
  Sensitive data includes the fields below, but new sensitive fields should be easily added to the function as needed:

The credit card number

The credit card expiry date

The credit card CVV value

The function returns the parsed string in the same format that it was provided, but with the sensitive data now masked.

```
  <?php

        $testData1 = "[orderId] => 212939129
        [orderNumber] => INV10001
        [salesTax] => 1.00
        [amount] => 21.00
        [terminal] => 5
        [currency] => 1
        [type] => purchase
        [avsStreet] => 123 Road
        [avsZip] => A1A 2B2
        [customerCode] => CST1001
        [cardId] => 18951828182
        [cardHolderName] => John Smith
        [cardNumber] => 5454545454545454
        [cardExpiry] => 1025
        [cardCVV] => 100";

    $testData2 = "Request=Credit Card.Auth Only&Version=4022&HD.Network_Status_Byte=*&HD.Application_ID=TZAHSK!&HD."
            . "Terminal_ID=12991kakajsjas&HD.Device_Tag=000123&07."
            . "POS_Entry_Capability=1&07.PIN_Entry_Capability=0&07.CAT_Indicator=0&07."
            . "Terminal_Type=4&07.Account_Entry_Mode=1&07.Partial_Auth_Indicator=0&07.Account_Card_Number="
            . "4242424242424242&07.Account_Expiry=1024&07.Transaction_Amount=142931&07."
            . "Association_Token_Indicator=0&17.CVV=200&17.Street_Address=123 Road SW&17.Postal_Zip_Code=90210&17.Invoice_Number=INV19291";


    $testData3 = '{
            "MsgTypId": 111231232300,
            "CardNumber": "4242424242424242",
            "CardExp": 1024,
            "CardCVV": 240,
            "TransProcCd": "004800",
            "TransAmt": "57608",
            "MerSysTraceAudNbr": "456211",
            "TransTs": "180603162242",
            "AcqInstCtryCd": "840",
            "FuncCd": "100",
            "MsgRsnCd": "1900",
            "MerCtgyCd": "5013",
            "AprvCdLgth": "6",
            "RtrvRefNbr": "1029301923091239",
        }';

    $testData4 = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                <Request>
                        <NewOrder>
                                <IndustryType>MO</IndustryType>
                                <MessageType>AC</MessageType>
                                <BIN>000001</BIN>
                                <MerchantID>209238</MerchantID>
                                <TerminalID>001</TerminalID>
                                <CardBrand>VI</CardBrand>
                                <CardDataNumber>5454545454545454</AccountNum>
                                <Exp>1026</Exp>
                                <CVVCVCSecurity>300</Exp>
                                <CurrencyCode>124</CurrencyCode>
                                <CurrencyExponent>2</CurrencyExponent>
                                <AVSzip>A2B3C3</AVSzip>
                                <AVSaddress1>2010 Road SW</AVSaddress1>
                                <AVScity>Calgary</AVScity>
                                <AVSstate>AB</AVSstate>
                                <AVSname>JOHN R SMITH</AVSname>
                                <OrderID>23123INV09123</OrderID>
                                <Amount>127790</Amount>
                        </NewOrder>
                </Request>";

    $parseNew = array("name", "amt", "amount"); //some optional fields to parse
    //this function will take a provided string, $data, and replace all credit card information including 16-digit numbers, expiry dates and 3-digit CVV numbers.
    //$parseNew is an optional field to parse other sensitive information that matches the type of information entered into $parseNew, such as the transaction amount.
    //if the strings in $parseNew matches any field in the data given, then that data will be parsed as well
    //assign each piece of given test data to a variable for each to be passed into helcimTest

    function helcimTest($data, $parseNew) {

        $lines = explode("\n", $data); //split data by new lines into an array

        if (count($lines) == 1) { //if there aren't any new lines, then periods are used
            $lines = explode(".", $data); //different splits can also be added with another if, like a ,
            //print_r($lines);
        }

        for ($currLine = 0; $currLine < count($lines); $currLine++) { //loop through the lines and check for credit card information keywords as well as if theres any matches in $parseNew

            $nonos = array("cvv", "exp", "expiry", "expire", "CVV", "Exp"); //keywords of default fields to be parsed, credit card numbers need to be searched for differently
            $nonos = array_merge($nonos, $parseNew); //take optional parse data types and add it to array of default credit card data types
            //checking credit card number first
            $cardPos = strpos($lines[$currLine], "card"); //find "card" as part of Card Number 

            if ($cardPos === false) {

                $cardPos = strpos($lines[$currLine], "Card");
            }

            if ($cardPos > 0) { //if "card" is in the line, we check if "number" is also
                $numberPos = strpos($lines[$currLine], "Number");

                if ($numberPos === false) {
                    $numberPos = strpos($lines[$currLine], "number");
                }

                if ($numberPos > 0) {

                    $matches = array();
                    preg_match_all('!\d+!', $lines[$currLine], $matches); //grabs all numbers in the line and throws them in an array
                    $numberLength = 0;

                    $digits = $matches[0]; //unpack array inside matches array

                    for ($i = 0; $i < count($digits); $i++) {

                        if (strlen($digits[$i]) == 16) {

                            $theNumber = $digits[$i];
                            $numberLength = strlen($digits[$i]);
                        }
                    }

                    if ($numberLength == 16) { //when all of these things are true then this number is definitely a credit card number

                        $lines[$currLine] = str_replace($theNumber, "****************", $lines[$currLine]);
                        //print_r($lines);         
                    }
                }
            }

            //credit card number check complete

            //now to check for everythign else
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($nonos); $i++) {

                $currNono = $nonos[$i]; //current type of data we are looking to parse

                if(strpos($lines[$currLine], $currNono) > 0){ //check to see if current parsing field exists on current line

                    preg_match_all("/\d+\.\d+|\d+|[A-Za-z]+/", $lines[$currLine], $matches);
                    $sensData = $matches[0]; //unpack array from wihtin another array

                    print_r($sensData);

                    for($f = 0; $f < count($sensData); $f++){ //if we find any fields we want to parse

                        if (strcmp($sensData[$f], $currNono) == true && $f+1 != count($sensData)){

                            $hash = str_repeat("*", strlen($sensData[$f+1]));
                            $lines[$currLine] = str_replace($sensData[$f+1], $hash, $lines[$currLine]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        print_r($lines);
    }

    echo "Data set 1:\n\n"; //print results
    helcimTest($testData1, $parseNew);
    echo "Data set 2:\n\n";
    helcimTest($testData2, $parseNew);
    echo "Data set 3:\n\n";
    helcimTest($testData3, $parseNew);
    echo "Data set 4:\n\n";
    helcimTest($testData4, $parseNew);
```

The output appears as such, some of the values are correctly parsed, and some feel totally random. The first part of the function handles the credit card number alone, which is consistently parsed correctly, it's when the function reaches its bottom half that the patterns I've laid out just don't make any sense when compared to the results:

```
    Data set 1:

    Array
    (
        [0] => amount
        [1] => 21.00
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => cardExpiry
        [1] => 1025
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => cardCVV
        [1] => 100
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => [orderId] => 212939129
        [1] =>             [orderNumber] => INV10001
        [2] =>             [salesTax] => 1.00
        [3] =>             [amount] => 21.00
        [4] =>             [terminal] => 5
        [5] =>             [currency] => 1
        [6] =>             [type] => purchase
        [7] =>             [avsStreet] => 123 Road
        [8] =>             [avsZip] => A1A 2B2
        [9] =>             [customerCode] => CST1001
        [10] =>             [cardId] => 18951828182
        [11] =>             [cardHolderName] => John Smith
        [12] =>             [cardNumber] => ****************
        [13] =>             [cardExpiry] => ****
        [14] =>             [cardCVV] => ***
    )
    Data set 2:

    Array
    (
        [0] => Account
        [1] => Expiry
        [2] => 1024
        [3] => 07
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => Request=Credit Card
        [1] => Auth Only&Version=4022&HD
        [2] => Network_Status_Byte=*&HD
        [3] => Application_ID=TZAHSK!&HD
        [4] => Terminal_ID=12991kakajsjas&HD
        [5] => Device_Tag=000123&07
        [6] => POS_Entry_Capability=1&07
        [7] => PIN_Entry_Capability=0&07
        [8] => CAT_Indicator=0&07
        [9] => Terminal_Type=4&07
        [10] => Account_Entry_Mode=1&07
        [11] => Partial_Auth_Indicator=0&07
        [12] => Account_Card_Number=****************&07
        [13] => Account_******=****&**
        [14] => Transaction_Amount=142931&07
        [15] => Association_Token_Indicator=0&17
        [16] => CVV=200&17
        [17] => Street_Address=123 Road SW&17
        [18] => Postal_Zip_Code=90210&17
        [19] => Invoice_Number=INV19291
    )
    Data set 3:

    Array
    (
        [0] => CardExp
        [1] => 1024
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => CardCVV
        [1] => 240
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => {
        [1] =>                 "MsgTypId": 111231232300,
        [2] =>                 "CardNumber": "****************",
        [3] =>                 "CardExp": ****,
        [4] =>                 "CardCVV": ***,
        [5] =>                 "TransProcCd": "004800",
        [6] =>                 "TransAmt": "57608",
        [7] =>                 "MerSysTraceAudNbr": "456211",
        [8] =>                 "TransTs": "180603162242",
        [9] =>                 "AcqInstCtryCd": "840",
        [10] =>                 "FuncCd": "100",
        [11] =>                 "MsgRsnCd": "1900",
        [12] =>                 "MerCtgyCd": "5013",
        [13] =>                 "AprvCdLgth": "6",
        [14] =>                 "RtrvRefNbr": "1029301923091239",
        [15] =>             }
    )
    Data set 4:

    Array
    (
        [0] => Exp
        [1] => 1026
        [2] => Exp
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => CVVCVCSecurity
        [1] => 300
        [2] => Exp
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => CurrencyExponent
        [1] => 2
        [2] => CurrencyExponent
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => AVSname
        [1] => JOHN
        [2] => R
        [3] => SMITH
        [4] => AVSname
    )
    Array
    (
        [0] => <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
        [1] =>                     <Request>
        [2] =>                             <NewOrder>
        [3] =>                                     <IndustryType>MO</IndustryType>
        [4] =>                                     <MessageType>AC</MessageType>
        [5] =>                                     <BIN>000001</BIN>
        [6] =>                                     <MerchantID>209238</MerchantID>
        [7] =>                                     <TerminalID>001</TerminalID>
        [8] =>                                     <CardBrand>VI</CardBrand>
        [9] =>                                     <CardDataNumber>****************</AccountNum>
        [10] =>                                     <***>1026</***>
        [11] =>                                     <CVVCVCSecurity>***</***>
        [12] =>                                     <CurrencyCode>124</CurrencyCode>
        [13] =>                                     <****************>*</****************>
        [14] =>                                     <AVSzip>A2B3C3</AVSzip>
        [15] =>                                     <AVSaddress1>2010 Road SW</AVSaddress1>
        [16] =>                                     <AVScity>Calgary</AVScity>
        [17] =>                                     <AVSstate>AB</AVSstate>
        [18] =>                                     <*******>**** * *****</*******>
        [19] =>                                     <OrderID>23123INV09123</OrderID>
        [20] =>                                     <Amount>127790</Amount>
        [21] =>                             </NewOrder>
        [22] =>                     </Request>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Question: Are you sure that your XML Data is correct?

```
 <CardDataNumber>5454545454545454</AccountNum>
```

Shouldn't it look like this:

```
 <CardDataNumber>5454545454545454</CardDataNumber>
```

or like this:

```
 <AccountNum>5454545454545454</AccountNum>
```

same Problem in this Line:

```
 <CVVCVCSecurity>300</Exp>
```

so if you change your code-part from:

```
if (strcmp($sensData[$f], $currNono) == true && $f+1 != count($sensData)){
  $hash = str_repeat("*", strlen($sensData[$f+1]));
  $lines[$currLine] = str_replace($sensData[$f+1], $hash, $lines[$currLine]);
}
```

to this:

```
if ($f > 0 && $f < count($sensData)-1){
  $hash = str_repeat("*", strlen($sensData[$f]));
  $lines[$currLine] = str_replace($sensData[$f], $hash, $lines[$currLine]);
}
```

Let me explain my solution:
The if Statement checks now that if $f is not 0 (the first match in the brackets) and not count of matches - 1 (so the last match in the brackets). If so, it's the content and this is changed with the fitting length of Asterix (*) characters.

**In my Test it do the work right, please comment if you have any questions!**

> **HINT!** CurrencyExponent is matched because it contains **Exp** as you see: Currency**Exp**onent

Comment: This definitely fixed the asterisk problem. Thank you so much! IF you're interested, I have one more problem, some keywords are found as evidenced by the arrays I've printed out but some of them aren't actually keywords, some of them are found and then don't get an asterisk either

Comment: Also, this is just the data I was given, it was never intended to be used as actual XML as far as I know